# Что такое сервер приложения?

Tags: сервер, веб-сервер

Из всего прочитанного в интернете мне удалось понять, что существуют 2 вида серверов: статические и динамические. Статические сервера включают в себя "сервер-железо" и "сервер-ПО", которое работает с HTTP и URL. Динамические сервера содержат все то, что содержат статические + сервер приложения и базу данных. Вся инфа [отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_web_server#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80,%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20HTTP.).

То есть по сути динамический сервер называется таким из-за работы сервер приложения, который может изменять файлы, передаваемые по HTTP, налету.

У меня возник вопрос. Получается, что сервер приложения - это какой-то код, который позволяет обрабатывать файлы. Но судя по этой цитате, это не совсем так (вряд ли код может содержать веб-сервер):

[Источник](https://ru.gadget-info.com/difference-between-web-server#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%2C%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80.)

> **Сервер приложений может содержать веб-серверы**, поэтому он считается более мощным, чем веб-сервер.

Здесь мне скорее всего не понятно само строение или структура этого сервера приложения. Для чего и каким образом он содержит этот веб-сервер?

Также не понятна эта [фраза](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%2C%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%20API%20(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9.):

> Сервер приложений действует как набор компонентов, доступных разработчику программного обеспечения через API (интерфейс прикладного программирования), определённый самой платформой.

Получается, что если API поддерживает взаимодействие 2-ух программ, то в этом случае API может поддерживать взаимодействие между сервером приложения и какой-то любой другой программой. А всегда ли API поддерживает работу с сервером приложений, API работает только с сервером приложений?

Comment: я не хочу умничать, но, мне кажется, Вы читаете какие то не те источники. Не хочу катить бочку на авторитетную Википедию и т.п., но в общем здесь идёт "спор о терминах". Посмотрите на это с другой стороны: Сервер - это любая "штука", которая обслуживает "запросы". Вам компьютер ответил на ping? О! Это - сервер!

Comment: А то, что Вы пишете про статическиие и динамические сервера - обычно, мне кажется, называется "статическим контентом" и "динамическим контентом". И - еще, если уточнить, что речь идет о HTTP - серверах, всё становится на свои места. Но я всё же советую Вам разбить вопрос на несколько вопросов, так как в текущем виде на него трудно ответить

Comment: Сервер — это программа, принимающая входящие запросы от клиентов. Веб-сервер — программа, принимающая входящие запросы по протоколу http. Также сервером называют компьютер, основным назначением которого является запуск программ-серверов. Всю остальную «серверную» терминологию я считаю малополезной шелухой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

я рискну ответить на вопрос, хотя, скорее всего, это не будет полным и законеченым ответом.

Мне кажется, что то непонимание, которое у Вас есть, происходит от обилия терминов и их "исторического напластования"

1. То, что Вы называете "статическиие и динамические сервера" - обычно, мне кажется, называется "статическим контентом" и "динамическим контентом".
2. то, что в тексте назывется серверами приложений - нужно понимать просто как "веб сервер без морды", как бы грубо это ни звучало. Это - программа, которая по HTTP принимает запросы и по HTTP же отвечает. Обычно это называют REST - протоколом (Representational state transfer)

Еще один распространённый термин для "серверов приложений" - это "веб-служба".

> А всегда ли API поддерживает работу с сервером приложений?

Сам  термин "сервер приложений" - это некая историческая шелуха.

Поясню свою мысль. На этапе зарождения WEB'а возможности написать файл с гиперссылками и отдавать его в примитивный браузер типа [мозаики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NCSA_Mosaic) в общем всем хватало.

Но хотелось "динамики" например, счетчика числа посетителей на странице. Для этого использовался [CGI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGI) (Common Gateway Interface).

Фактически, это означало, что в ответ на запрос из браузера на сервере выполнится программа, и результат её выполнения будет показан в браузере.

Чтобы "хорошо продавать" эту возможность ( а веб-сервера были не только бесплатными open source, но иногда и очень даже платными, типа [Microsoft IIS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) и [IBM  WebSphere](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSphere) ) - был придуман *маркетинговый термин* "сервер приложений".

Который означал не более и не менее, чем возможность в ответ на запрос пользователя выполнить некий код, который на этот запрос ответит. В этом была разница с сервером, который умеет только "тупо хостить файлы"

Далее - под API, наверное, следует понимать "взаимодействие по заранее согласованному протоколу", но применительно к HTTP - серверам это в 99% случаев следует читать как REST API.

Что это такое?

Объясню на примере. Пускай у меня есть база данных с ценной информацией.

Я могу сделать веб - сервер, который на своих страницах будет показывать эту информацию по запросам пользователя.

А могу предоставить интерфейс к своей базе данных, и многие - многие сервера в интернете начнут показывать эту информацию на своих страницах, обращаясь за самой информацией ко мне. По API. При этом у меня может вообще не быть "веб сервера, на котором есть страницы для просмотра посетителями".

Я надеюсь, что я смог - в этом коротком ответе - помочь Вам разобраться в терминах. Но если есть уточняющие вопросы - пишите!

**Дополнение**

я перечитал Ваш вопрос, и решил немного дополнить ответ вот в какой части:

> > Сервер приложений может содержать веб-серверы, поэтому он считается более мощным, чем веб-сервер.

> Здесь мне скорее всего не понятно само строение или структура этого сервера приложения. Для чего и каким образом он содержит этот веб-сервер?

Я попытаюсь "на пальцах" рассказать, что имется в виду. Для этого посмотрим на стуктуру того, что вообще есть во всех этих серверах.

1. Есть программа, которая реализует HTTP - протокол. Она просто умеет получать HTTP-запрос и в ней есть модуль, который *пытается* на это запрос ответить.
2. Обычно эту программу просто "привязывают" к файловой системе WEB-сервера,  и "модуль отвечания" работает по такому алгоритму: "К тебе пришел запрос? Посмотри, есть ли на диске файл, название которого соответствует запросу. Если есть - выдай этот файл в ответ на запрос, если нет - покажи страницу с 404-й ошибкой". Это - то что называется "статический контент", или "статический сервер" (как бы не передёргивало меня от этого термина)
3. Что такое "динамический сервер"? Это когда "модуль отвечания" в программе, которая обслуживает запросы, учат еще одному фокусу: "... а вот если к тееб придёт запрос определенного вида - то вместо отдачи файла пользователю выполни вот эту программу, и отдай пользоваетлю результаты её выполнения".

вот именно в этом смысле "Сервер приложений может содержать веб-серверы" - они имеют в виду, что, для того, чтобы принять запрос и отправить ответ - нужен модуль работы с HTTP протоколом, и называют его "веб-сервер". В этом смысле "динамический сервер" собержит "веб-сервер" в своём составе.

Comment: _вот именно в этом смысле "Сервер приложений может содержать веб-серверы" - они имеют в виду, что, для того, чтобы принять запрос и отправить ответ - нужен модуль работы с HTTP протоколом, и называют его "веб-сервер"_ а что тогда содержит веб-сервер для работы с HTTP (ПО сервер, как говорится на MDN) при отсутствии сервера приложений (т.е. если говорить про статический контент, статический сервер)? Сервер-железо?

Comment: @Eva - > а что тогда содержит веб-сервер для работы с HTTP при отсутствии сервера приложений - я думаю, при отсутствии сервера приложений модуль работы с HTTP (это штука, которая умеет принимать запрос и отдавать ответ) имеет простейшую инструкцию "приняв запрос, возьми файл, если он существует, и отправь его в качестве ответа". То есть, имеется в виду сервер - программа, но которая не умеет запускать "другие программы", а умеет только отдавать готовые файлы.

Comment: вы наверное не поняли моего вопроса)) вопрос был в том, где находится программа по работе с HTTP - на железе или на сервере приложений? Хотя, наверное, и там, и там, в любом случае надо же сначала обработать запрос _(обрабатывает, как я понимаю, железо)_, а уже потом выдать ответ _(обрабатывает, как я понимаю, или железо, или сервер приложения)_. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Eva обработкой и выдачей ответов занимаются программы, а программы запускаются на железе. «Сервер приложений» это просто ещё одна программа, наличие или отсутствие которой зависит только от ваших личных предпочтений

Comment: @Eva - там в комментарии выше Вам уже ответили.. в общем, не заморачивайтесь на железе - всё, что работает с HTTP, - это программы. На железе работают только более низкоуровневые протоколы.

Comment: @S.H. Я просто все еще пытаюсь понять как понимать эту фразу:"_Сервер приложений может содержать веб-серверы, поэтому он считается более мощным, чем веб-сервер."_ Здесь, судя по ответам на мой вопрос, сервер приложений может содержать просто какие-то другие внутренние программы-серверы, которые будут помогать в ему в работе, а сам http сервер, который обрабатывает запросы, находится на железе

Comment: @Eva http-сервер это программа, которая может находиться внутри сервера приложений (а может и не находиться, это уж как захочется); никто не обрабатывает запросы на чистом железе, всё идёт через программы

Comment: @andreymal В смысле _никто не обрабатывает запросы на чистом железе_? А как же в тех случаях, когда сервера приложений нет? http-запрос же должен где-то обрабатываться... Где же он обрабатывается, когда нет этого сервера приложений?

Comment: @Eva - я советую Вам критически относиться к этой фразе, потому что она 1) изначально включала в себя неоднозначности, присущие языку вообще 2) была переведена, что не добавило ей однозначности. Слова "считается более мощным" можно понимать как "позволяет выполнить больше функций". Такое трактование, скорее всего, близкО к исходному смыслу

Comment: @Eva значит обрабатывается в какой-то другой программе

Answer (score 3):

Что/кто такой(-ое) "сервер"?

англ: serve - служить; +er --> **server - тот, кто обслуживает**.

Простыми словами "сервер" это то, что обслуживает (исполняет) запросы. **Исполнитель**.

Исполнитель (*сервер*) -- это приложение. Однако этим же "словом" также называют железо на котором работает это приложение(-я). Да, на одном железе (*сервере*) могут быть запущены несколько приложений (*серверов*).

*Деды от "айти"* не перевели, в своё время, теперь вот такие вопросы.

Далее по наследию от *дедов*.

**"Статичный, статический"**

англ (прил): static -- неподвижный.

**"Динамичный, динамический и прочее динамо-"**

англ (прил): dynamic -- действующий, работающий, живой.

**"Веб"**

англ: web -- паутина, сеть.

Соединяем всё до кучи.

**Веб-сервер** -- исполнитель, который обрабатывает сетевые запросы, созданные по тем или иным правилам (договорённостям) (англ: **protocol**): TCP/IP, HTTP и т.д.

**Сервер-приложений** -- исполнитель, на котором выполняется какое-либо прикладное приложение.

**Статический-сервер** -- исполнитель, который также является ещё и *веб-сервером*, в задачи которого входит выдать те или иные данные, которые уже имеются у него. Т.е. ничего *нового* он при обращении к нему не создаёт. Например, у него есть набор изображений, вот, при обращении к нему, он и будет выдавать лишь эти изображения.

**Динамический-сервер** -- исполнитель, который может быть *веб-сервером*, а может и не быть им, но в любом случае он является *сервером-приложений*. Если с ним можно общаться по сети, то значит это *веб-сервер*, если его задача, например, просто вычислять простые числа, то для этого никакой *веб* не нужен.

Ну и несколько слов про *API* исполнителя приложений.

К примеру, возьмём самовоз (англ: auto- (само-); mobile (подвижный)). У него есть рычаг переключения передач. Так вот допустимые положения для этого рычага являются *API*, т.е. способами для переключения передач, которые предоставлены разработчиками самовоза для этих нужд.

Наглядно положения передач можно описать так:

- 1-я: /влево/вверх
- 2-я: /влево/вниз
- ..
- 5-я: /вправо/вверх
- Задняя: /вправо/вниз

Для исполнителя приложений всё тоже самое. Есть набор мест (положений) при обращении к которым (с указанием дополнительных данных, если это необходимо) будет выполнено то или иное действие этим самым приложением. Например:

создать заметку: /createArticle, /create-article, /создатьЗаметку, /заметку-создать (выбор названия всецело зависит от разработчиков приложений).