# Как работают web api и нужны ли им серверы

Tags: веб-программирование, сервер, webapi

Какая архитектура обмена данными между приложением WebAPI, например написанных на c#, java или других компилируемых языках и сервером?

Когда я пишу какой-нибудь контроллер, то у каждого прописывается часть пути в URL на программном уровне в c#. Зачем тогда этому приложению нужен сервер? Сколько связанных задач в диспетчере будет отображаться: сервер и webapi? Достаточно ли одного webapi? Ведь, как я понимаю, webapi является отдельным процессом, который прослушивает установленный внутри кода порт и обрабатывает его. Зачем тогда нужен ещё и сервер? Это два связанных процесса или модульных (независимых)? Или процесс api запускается при каждом запросе к серверу? Тогда нагрузка на процессор будет высокой.

UPD: под сервером я подразумеваю процесс типа IIS или APACHE. Нужна ли они, если webapi сам является процессом, прослушивающий определенный для него порт?

UPD2: похоже, я нашла ответ: https://habr.com/ru/post/426957/. Коротко: сервер всего-то перенаправляет запрос в связанный процесс webapi. Но остаётся вопрос, как происходит передача данных в обратном направлении?

UPD3: в вопросе я рассматриваю одну часть - пк, который выступает как сервер. Предполагается, что на нём работает два процесса: серверное приложение типа IIS, и второе - webapi (на c#). Потому что все webapi asp.net запускаются из-под IIS или другого сервера. И вопрос был в том, зачем нужен IIS, если все настройки подключения к сокету и маршрутизация уже программируются в webapi. https://habr.com/ru/company/microsoft/blog/145178/

Мда... Наверное ответ лежал на поверхности. Похоже iis реально просто запускает процесс и перенаправляет ему запросы, и обе части являются серверным приложением. И по сути, приложение asp.net может так же работать без iis, т.к. что iis, что webapi работают на определённом порту. Вопрос только в том, кому отправлять клиентские запросы. https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/2.7.php

И цитата из статьи https://habr.com/ru/company/microsoft/blog/145178/ немного приоткрыла ответ:

> Для предоставления доступа к API сервиса не всегда является целесообразным разворачивать его на базе сервера IIS. Если сервис не является частью какого-либо веб-приложения, имеет смысл запускать его на базе собственной инфраструктуры.

Как уложу информацию, постараюсь написать ответ.

Comment: Сервер связывает внешний мир с приложением, внутри приложения уже на уровне кода своя маршрутизация

Comment: Плюсанул вопрос - по моему, это хорошая попытка самостоятельно разобраться.

Comment: Там в комментариях к моему ответу andreymal обратил моё внимание на вопрос "зачем нужен IIS". Коороткий ответ: это просто традиция. Традиционно отладку WEB - приложений делают с помощью определенного типа проектов, и они запускаются под IIS Express. Но никто не мешает взять "консольный" проект, руками добавить туда кестрел и т.п. и всё сделать from the scratch, см, например, вот такой мой вопрос  - ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1245445/

Comment: Со спецификой дотента я не знаком, но есть ряд общих причин, почему перед сервером приложения может быть желательно иметь ещё один веб-сервер: [Нужен ли nginx для node.js сервера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/880851) — там про nodejs и nginx, но, думаю, многое из сказанного там применимо и к дотнету с IIS тоже

Answer (score 2):

Судя по тому, как много у Вас отдельных маленьких вопросов в одном общем вопросе - у Вас какая то каша в понимании архитектуры веб приложений...

Давайте по порядку.

Вот есть код. Который должен выполниться в ответ на некоторый реквест. Так как Вы говорите про "пути на программном уровне" - значит, про маршрутизацию запросов Вы знаете.

И этот код написан, к примеру, на C#. Или на java.

Нужен ли такому коду сервер? Конечно, нужен! Иначе этот код просто некому будет выполнить.

Дальше - начинаются игры с тем, как оптимально - в смысле производительности (throughput) и времени ответа - загрузить сервер процессами, которые будут отвечать пользователю.  Но это - уже совсем другая история, сейчас Вам достаточно знать, что web-сервер - это отдельный процесс.

**Дополнение**, дополненное после комментария "Но если приложение, которое обрабатывает запрос способен работать без сервера, зачем он тогда им?":

Также, Вы можете прочитать вот таккие вот [вопрос-ответ: Что такое сервер приложения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344625/)

Теперь попробую кратко ответить на комментарий.

Смотрите. Есть некая путаница в терминах. В основном - потому что людям лень каждый раз говорить "Рестфул приложение, хранящее своё состояние и взамиодействующее по расширенному протоколу HTTP с сервером Apache", и они говоря просто "клиент" или "сервер".

Сервер - любая "штука", которая позвоялет еще кому то - людям или программам - использовать свои ресурсы.

Когда Вы делаете более-менее сложную вещь, то часть "работы" выполняет сервер. Это происходит на логическом уровне. Возьмём в качетве примера игру, где ингроки ходят по полю и наперегонки ищут клад (или мину и возможность на неё подорваться...). В этом слкчае *логично*, что клиент *на самом деле не знает*, где находится клад. Иначе он мог бы "хакнуть" программу и воспользоваться этим знанием, получив нечестное преимущество. Поэтому эта информация *на логическом уровне* должна быть известна только серверу.

Дальше ничанаются частности: а по какому протоколу обращаться к серверу? По кастомному (то есть, только что сами придумали?). Или по какому то известному?

Исторически сложилось так, что HTTP *прижился* в качестве универсального протокола. И если у Вас есть програма, которая делает что то простое и понятное, но её надо разделить на клиент и сервер - то Вы уже на автомате делите её на две части, и делаете так, что сервер "обмазывается" прослойкой для обработки HTTP - запросов (это и есть стандартна работа WEB-сервера).

Если мои объяснения не помогли - уточните вопрос, например, исправив его. Или напишите в комментариях, еще подумаем.

Comment: Я, наверное, забыла добавить про IIS и APACHE. Обычно для того, чтобы тестировать приложение, поднимается ещё и сервер. На этом сервере обычно хранятся статические данные, однако есть возможность добавить CGI. Но если приложение, которое обрабатывает запрос способен работать без сервера, зачем он тогда им?

Comment: @AB - я немного дополнил ответ, после Вашего комментария

Comment: Зачем нужен сервер в принципе - понятно, а зачем нужен конкретно IIS, если в дотнете есть встроенный сервер (возможно речь про Kestrel?) - непонятно (см. свежую правку вопроса)

Comment: @andreymal - спасибо, я там в комментах немного дополнил ответ...

Comment: @andreymal, да, именно так (почитала ещё в интернете). Однако по принципу Asp.net работают и другие платформы с другими языками. Похоже путаница была в понятиях. Каждый трактует так как хочет. Просто хотелось это унифицировать (в моём случае в виде процессов, которые висят в диспетчере задач и прослушивают определённый порт).

Comment: @AB Много где уже есть встроенные веб-серверы, поэтому необходимость не такая большая во "внешнем" веб-сервере. Но внутренний веб-сервер сможет обрабатывать только один домен, поэтому отдельный веб-сервер скорее всего будет работать у Вас в качестве proxy-сервера.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, да. Тут ещё и двойственность понятие сервера: с технической части это компьютер, а с программной - программа. У меня всегда ассоциация proxy-сервера была с отдельным компьютером, но это бессмысленно в рамках приложений. Спасибо за комментарий!

Comment: @AB "Сервер" и "веб-сервер" – понятия разные. Веб-сервер сервером просто иногда сокращенно называют, но по контексту понятно.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar сервер - это программа, принимающая запросы от клиентов. Веб-сервер - одна из разновидностей сервера